# Trigger jquery tab active by data-tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've checked around in here, but not found my answer. I have my code below:

```
<div class="gdlr-session-item gdlr-tab-session-item gdlr-item">
<div class="gdlr-session-item-head">
<div class="gdlr-session-item-head-info gdlr-active" data-tab="gdlr-tab-1">
<div class="gdlr-session-head-day">Day 1</div>
<div class="gdlr-session-head-date">23 May 2016</div>
</div>

<div class="gdlr-session-item-head-info" data-tab="gdlr-tab-2">
<div class="gdlr-session-head-day">Day 2</div>
<div class="gdlr-session-head-date">24 May 2016</div>
</div>

<div class="gdlr-session-item-tab-content gdlr-tab-1 gdlr-active" style="display: block;">
Content here
</div>
<div class="gdlr-session-item-tab-content gdlr-tab-2" style="display: none;">
Content here
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
// script for session tab item
    $('.gdlr-session-item-head-info').click(function(){
    if( $(this).hasClass('gdlr-active') ) return;
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('gdlr-active');
    $(this).addClass('gdlr-active');

    var selected_tab = $(this).attr('data-tab');
    $(this).parent('.gdlr-session-item-head').siblings('.gdlr-session-item-tab-content').hide();
    $(this).parent('.gdlr-session-item-head').siblings('.' + selected_tab).fadeIn();
});
```

In the default, The day 1 will active and show the content from class: gdlr-tab-1.

I need help to active the day 2 instead day 1. Thank so much for all help!

Live demo: http://goodlayers.tienloc.net/keynote/.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Not sure what plugin or UI framework you are using. I would recommend to use some generics plugins like - jQuery UI https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ for any tab related functionalities.

Comment: Could it be that you only have to set the class `gdlr-active` on the other tab and content?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have experience with jquery, I'm just trying to help my friend :(.

I updated the link to live preview.

Answer (score 0):

Check if below code helps.

You can hide all the content div first and then can show (fade in) the required div using the data attr, same applies to add and remove active class.

```
$('.gdlr-session-item-head-info').click(function(){
  if( $(this).hasClass('gdlr-active') ) return;
  $('.gdlr-active').removeClass('gdlr-active');
  $(this).addClass('gdlr-active');

  var selected_tab = $(this).attr('data-tab');
  $(".gdlr-session-item-tab-content").hide();
  $("."+selected_tab).addClass('gdlr-active');
  $("."+selected_tab).fadeIn();    
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't have experience with jquery, so I don't know how to customize it to fit my question :(. Thank again!

Comment: Please check green tick if it has resolved your query. P.S. to change the target you just need to change the value of `data-tab` attribute.